# Merge two lists into a serparate list

Tags: c++, list, templates, stl

I am trying to merge two lists into a seperate list. I know how to merge two lists, but I am not sure how to go about merging the values into an empty third list, without the values of the two lists changing.

```
list <int> FirstList, SecondList, ThirdList;

FirstList.merge(SecondList);
```

Comment: You can just assign the merged two list to the third one.

Comment: @HamzaAnis [merge](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/merge/) clears the list that's being merged.

Comment: @scohe001 But I am saying to do like `ThirsList.assign(FirstList.begin(), FirstList.end())`.  The `SecondList` would be cleared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the generic merge algorithm, which copies from the two input ranges, rather than the specialized one for lists (which transfers the nodes into the third list):

```
std::merge(FirstList.begin(), FirstList.end(),
           SecondList.begin(), SecondList.end(),
           std::back_inserter(ThirdList));
```